# function root finding by secant method in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this matlab code for calculating the root of a function by using secant method :

```
syms x
f=@(x) x.^2-2;
x0=1;
x1=5;
tol=0.01;

for i=1:100

    if (f(x0)-f(x1)) < 0.00001
        break;
    end

xn = x0-((f(x0)*(x0-x1))/(f(x0)-f(x1)));

    if abs(xn-x0) < tol*abs(xn)
       break;
    end
    x0=xn;
    x1=x0;
end


fprintf('the root is %g\n', xn)
```

When I run the code , matlab says : `Undefined function or variable 'xn'.`
Why it says that ? I did define the xn in the code !!!

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an absolute value in this if statement:

```
if abs(f(x0)-f(x1)) < 0.00001
    break;
end
```

Without this, the for loop breaks before you get to your `xn` definition, not because `f(x0)` is close to `f(x1)`, but because the result is negative.

Running it through, you have a second problem, these lines need to be swapped around, otherwise they end up being equal, which is not what you want.

```
x0=xn;
x1=x0;
```

Comment: thank you very much brother ... I did remove the if statement you mentioned it was wrong and I got a root  ... Now how can I correct my if statement that you mentioned .. Is it that I do not need that if statement ? :)

Comment: No need to remove it, just add in the `abs` and it should work.

Comment: The first if statement breaks if `f(x0)` is approximately equal to `f(x1)`. The second if statement should break if `x1` is approximately equal to `x2`. You can use either or both, depending on your requirements.